# Flip animation clips the previously scaled ImageView on API 19

Tags: android, animation

I've played with the [FlipImageView](https://github.com/castorflex/FlipImageView) project and noticed one rather curious issue. When I'm running the sample contained within the project, everything works just fine. But, when I scale the `FlipImageView` manually (using [View.setScaleX(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)) and [View.setScaleY(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleY(float)) methods) this sample works fine just for devices with API version 16-18, and it clips the `FlipImageView` during the animation to the size of the unscaled image if sample is run on the device with the 19-th version of API. Here are screenshots:

[image]
The star is clipped, API 19

[image]
The star isn't clipped, API 18

I've set the visibility of all other widgets to `GONE` and changed the image's width to `wrap_content` to make an issue even more obvious. I see this behavior both on emulators and on real devices.

The code of the custom animation looks like so:

```
public class FlipAnimator extends Animation {
    // fields declarations omitted

    public void setToDrawable(Drawable to) {
        toDrawable = to;
        visibilitySwapped = false;
    }

    public FlipAnimator() {
        setFillAfter(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        camera = new Camera();
        this.centerX = width / 2;
        this.centerY = height / 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final double radians = Math.PI * interpolatedTime;
        float degrees = (float) (180.0 * radians / Math.PI);

        if(mIsRotationReversed){ 
            degrees = -degrees;
        }

        if (interpolatedTime >= 0.5f) {
            if(mIsRotationReversed){ degrees += 180.f; } else{ degrees -= 180.f; }

            if (!visibilitySwapped) {
                setImageDrawable(toDrawable);
                visibilitySwapped = true;
            }
        }

        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        camera.save();
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) (150.0 * Math.sin(radians)));
        camera.rotateX(mIsRotationXEnabled ? degrees : 0);
        camera.rotateY(mIsRotationYEnabled ? degrees : 0);
        camera.rotateZ(mIsRotationZEnabled ? degrees : 0);
        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        camera.restore();

        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    }
}
```

I've searched through the [diff between API version 18 and 19](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/19/changes.html) and didn't find any changes in the `Matrix` or `Camera` classes which are used  in the [Animation.applyTransformation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#getTransformation(long,%20android.view.animation.Transformation)) method. I didn't find any changes in the `Animation` class itself neither.

What is the source of this problem?

**Upd:** the clipping occurs *only during the animation* - when it ends, the `FlipImageView` is drawn in its full size.